# RStudio ggplot Logarithmic graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, logarithm

I have a really easy data frame with two columns. We can just call them X and Y. Y is in feet and X is in cubic feet per second. I want to do a log graph and obtain the equation for the line but I have no idea how to accomplish this. I am guessing this is easier then I am making it out to be.  I am currently using ggplot and I am getting really strange graphs. I attached a picture of what I am getting but the graph dows not make sense. It should be a straight line. [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3CKY.png)

```
a %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Discharge, Gageheight)) +
  geom_point())
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi OP, can you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?  Share at least a portion of your data frame via copying and pasting into the question the output of `dput(your_df)` - should start with `structure(...`.  Then also please share the plot code you are currently using, and if possible, an image of your current output.

Comment: Thank you I added your suggestions. I am learning how to ask the questions so people understand.

Comment: Maybe I need to adjust the x axis because the data goes to 25000

Comment: I added a picture of my odd results. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use a really simple dataset like yours and using this:

```
ggplot(data = easy_dataset, mapping = aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point()
```

It gave me the expected graph.

Comment: It is strange because I can get it to graph but the information looks really odd. Basically a bunch of lines one on top of another. .

Comment: your code works for me but it gives rescaling problem using "coord_trans(x = 'log10')". What do you mean for information? Anyways you should log the data before putting them in ggplot and then using the new variable for the y axis.

Comment: It is almost like the graph is not large enough for the data. The graph has 11 lines gradually moving from 0 to the top of the y axis.

Comment: ggplot(data = a, mapping = aes(Discharge, Gageheight)) + geom_point()+
  xlim(15, 30000)